# Make links clickable in PHP with twitterlibphp?

Tags: php, function, twitter

Hey guys, I'm using Twitter's PHP API, called [twitterlibphp](http://github.com/jdp/twitterlibphp/blob/af84b45451d464e432829a63bd6700494fb63558/twitter.lib.php), and it works well, but there's one thing that I need to be able to initiate, which is the linking of URLs and @username replies.  I already have the function for this written up correctly (it is called clickable_link($text);) and have tested it successfully.  I am not too familiar with parts of twitterlibphp (link goes to source code), and I am not sure where to put the function clickable_link() in order to make URLs and @username's clickable.  I hope that is enough information, thanks a lot.

EDIT:
In addition, I would like only one status to come up in the function GetFriendsTimeline(), right now 20 come up, is there any easy way to limit it to one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would extend the `Twitter` class and put the functionality in my own `getUserTimeline` method.

```
class MyTwitter extends Twitter
{
    public function getUserTimeline()
    {
        $result = parent::getUserTimeline();

        // Your functionality ...

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put clickable_link() in twitterlibphp.  Instead, call it right before you output a status message.  Example:

```
$twitter = new Twitter('username', 'password');
$result = $twitter->getUserTimeline();

... parse the $result XML here ...

echo 'Status : '.clickable_link($status);
```